# ¿Cómo puedo hacer cambiar de color las letras?

Tags: javascript

quiero que las letras cambien de color a verde cuando la repuesta es verdadera y rojo cuando es falsa y en amarillo cuando la respuesta se aproxime a la correcta, muchas gracias por la ayuda!

```
let intento = 6;
let palabra= "apple";
let button = document.getElementById("guess-button");

button.addEventListener("click", intentar);


function intentar(){
    const INTENTO = leerIntento();
console.log(INTENTO);
}

function leerIntento(){
   const INPUT = document.getElementById ("guess-input");
   let intento = INPUT.value;
   return intento.toUpperCase()
}
```

Comment: Puedes explicar un poco el flujo del programa, lo ejecute y bien hice un botón y un input, coloque una palabra en el input luego le di click al botón y apareció la palabra en mayúscula cerrada en la consola.

La variable palabra para que es?, esta declarada pero no se utiliza.